# GWT RequestBuilder POST JSON application/json

Tags: json, gwt, post

I'm trying to send JSON data to a server.

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);
builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
builder.setRequestData(getJSONString());
builder.setCallback(myCallbackObject);
builder.send();
```

I do this in eclipse and I saw in the TCP/IP Monitor that my JSON Data is not transmitted as post in the request. If I ask for

```
builder.getRequestData();
```

I can see the JSON data is right there.

What do I need for the data to get on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be running into the browser's [same-origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_SOP) if the url that you are attempting to connect to is not from the same origin as your GWT `nocache.js` file.  Is your callback's `onFailure()` being called?  Also, see if `Request.getSatusCode()` returns `0`, which is indicative of SOP problems.

Comment: you are right, it was the SOP. When using the eclipse TCP/IP monitor it translates your communication port, hence when changing the port, the origin changes.

Answer (score 0):

To simply post JSON data with HTTP post, you can use [GWT Overlay Types](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html) to define a post method using JQuery. A possible snapshot:

```
public static native void post(String json) /*-{
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    $wnd.$.post(url, data);
}-*/;
```

I don't know if it is necessary to add JQuery to your HTML. I did, and worked. You can do this by adding the following line to your .html file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you can simply call that method in your java code:

```
post(json);
```

(: